# How to store a huge amount of URLs efficiently

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

I am working on a google chrome extension which adds a simple icon next to specific URLs,

---

- *What URLs does it add the icon to it?*

Well, it's basically an Anti-Rickroll extension, that blocks rickroll URLs

---

- *What's the problem?*

Basically, There's an absurdly huge amount of rickroll URLs in youtube, some of which are like this
"Rickroll but it's a different link so people cant memorize it" When I made the first prototype of my project I added just the original Rickroll and the "Rickroll'D" links and the music copyright URL which is in my code looks like this:

```
var stringsToBlock = ["/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ", "youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ",
 "/watch?v=okqEVeNqBhc", "youtu.be/okqEVeNqBhc", "/watch?v=BROWqjuTM0g",
  "youtu.be/BROWqjuTM0g", "/watch?v=IAISUDbjXj0", "youtu.be/IAISUDbjXj0",
   "/watch?v=4zKshWnI3ok", "youtu.be/4zKshWnI3ok", "/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0",
    "youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0", "/watch?v=6_b7RDuLwcI", "youtu.be/6_b7RDuLwcI",
     "/watch?v=DD70oKDlemE", "youtu.be/DD70oKDlemE", "/video/x1v6sh_rick-astley-never-gonna-give-you-up_music",
      "/video/x4g0cb_rick-astley-never-gonna-give-you-up_music", "/video/x1jl5p_rick-astley-never-gonna-give-you-up_creation",
       "/video/x46d2_rick-asley-never-gonna-give-you-up_music", "/video/x5ykzv_rick-roll_music",
        "/video/x58u4t_rick-roll-never-gonna-give-you-up-r_music", "/video/x58una_rick-roll-never-gonna-give-you-up-r_music",
         "/video/x22k2fw_rick-rolled_music", "/video/xsdji_rick-astley-never-gonna-give-you-up_music", 
          "/video/x1i1js_rick-astley-never-gonna-give-you-up_music", "/video/xeztvl_rick-astley-never-gonna-give-you-up_music",
           "/video/x6b3kz_rickroll_news", "/video/x5l8e6_rickroll_fun", "/2619976",
```

and yes this just only the 3 links I mentioned above not including the css which adds the icon

```
a[href*="/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
 a[href*="youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
  a[href*="/watch?v=okqEVeNqBhc"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
   a[href*="youtu.be/okqEVeNqBhc"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
    a[href*="/watch?v=BROWqjuTM0g"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
     a[href*="youtu.be/BROWqjuTM0g"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
      a[href*="/watch?v=IAISUDbjXj0"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
       a[href*="youtu.be/IAISUDbjXj0"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
        a[href*="/watch?v=4zKshWnI3ok"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
         a[href*="youtu.be/4zKshWnI3ok"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
          a[href*="/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
           a[href*="youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
            a[href*="/watch?v=6_b7RDuLwcI"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
             a[href*="youtu.be/6_b7RDuLwcI"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
              a[href*="/watch?v=DD70oKDlemE"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
               a[href*="youtu.be/DD70oKDlemE"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                a[href*="/video/x1v6sh_rick-astley-never-gonna-give-you-up_music"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                 a[href*="/video/x4g0cb_rick-astley-never-gonna-give-you-up_music"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                  a[href*="/video/x1jl5p_rick-astley-never-gonna-give-you-up_creation"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                   a[href*="/video/x46d2_rick-asley-never-gonna-give-you-up_music"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                    a[href*="/video/x5ykzv_rick-roll_music"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                     a[href*="/video/x58u4t_rick-roll-never-gonna-give-you-up-r_music"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                      a[href*="/video/x58una_rick-roll-never-gonna-give-you-up-r_music"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                       a[href*="/video/x22k2fw_rick-rolled_music"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                        a[href*="/video/xsdji_rick-astley-never-gonna-give-you-up_music"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                         a[href*="/video/x1i1js_rick-astley-never-gonna-give-you-up_music"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                          a[href*="/video/xeztvl_rick-astley-never-gonna-give-you-up_music"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                           a[href*="/video/x6b3kz_rickroll_news"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                            a[href*="/video/x5l8e6_rickroll_fun"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
                             a[href*="/2619976"]:not(.rickroll):not(.rickwimg):before,
```

obviously there is more to the code. So basically I searched youtube for rickroll and copied like 10 URLs and that sums the extension size to 1.5MB which is really big compared to OTHER useful extension so if I were to add ever rickroll link possible it would have come to like 100MB to 200MB, **So what useful way to automatically add URLs**

**I've few ideas in my head but I'm not sure if they work**

1. Get a background script to scan URLs if the title or description contains "Rickroll"
2. Work with YouTubes API to get a ginormous list of every possible rickroll link and store it in a server [Probably not allowed by chrome, lags a lot, Slower page loading, has a lot of permissions that makes the user suspicious, monthly subscription for the server which is not convenient as the first project]
3. Remake the entire code to make it efficient at finding URLs

Also, I'm a complete beginner so don't talk professionally to me, try to simplify the answer

Comment: There's no obvious solution so you'll have to try them all and see which one is better.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using regex matching for this. Since you have `/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ` and `youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ` you can clip the part of the id and check if those are present in your list. In this way you just store IDs!

```
var something = "/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
var test = something.match(/\/watch?v=(.*)/);
console.log(test[1]);
```

This would give you `dQw4w9WgXcQ`

You can also use regex to see if it contains particular character like 'rick-roll'

```
(new RegExp('rickroll')).test(url)
// or
/rickroll/.test(url)
```

You can also store the id / patterns in local-storage API to access them quickly!